# Is there a way to deploy an AutoGluon pre-built model in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, nlp, amazon-sagemaker, automl

I have generated a model for text Prediction using AutoGluon running in a SageMaker notebook instance. I already have a model folder, containing the following files:

```
hf_text folder;
assets.json
config.yaml
data_processor.pkl
df_preprocessor.pkl
DS_Store
model.ckpt
```

The model is working well but I am facing problems to deploy it to be called as an inference endpoint. All the documentation found is using TabularPredictor, but I need help for TextPredictor

Comment: Is the answer understandable and good for you? Please mark it as an answer if it is good.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a [Model](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/model.html) object?
This means that you would link a model file(s3 location) with DLC(deep learning container) which will enable you to deploy it to an Endpoint, what was your question.

The workflow is : Create Model -> Create Endpoint Configuration -> Create endpoint.

Here is an more detailed [example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-fundamentals/create-endpoint/create_endpoint.ipynb) with code, so you can figure out the rest.